# Sorting the Visual Studio Function List drop down to code order instead of alphabetical order

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010, intellisense

Colleague has asked the question and we were unable to find it - on the off chance thought it might be worth asking.

In a file you may have:

```
void BFunction()

void AFunction()

void CFunction()
```

now in the function list drop down, it'll have sorted those in alphabetical order:

```
AFunction
BFunction
CFunction
```

I prefer it this way actually. However my colleague is wondering if you can make that drop down sorted to the order the functions appear in the code, so that in the drop down it'd also be:

```
BFunction
AFunction
CFunction
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I guess you have to rename the functions.

Comment: yes I suggested that to my colleague as well, he didn't like the idea of renaming the functions in a large codebase.  But hey, that's what we did at a previous company, worked quite well.

Comment: You're kidding. At a previous company you named functions to coerce a certain sort order from the Intellisense code completion? You/your colleague do realize that these technologies are intended to make your life *easier*, right? If you want a method at the top, do you preface it with `Aardvark`?

Comment: Also, it if matters - the dropdown bar has typeahead find, so if you are looking for a method that starts with a specific/letter word, you can start typing it (after clicking on the function dropdown) to jump to it.

Comment: @Cody - No no, they merely put the functions in alphabetical order in the file.  The method was named first, and then placed.  But I'll use the 'it was like that when I got there' defense ;)

Comment: It's 2023. Can Visual Studio *still* not list the function names in the order we write them, rather than sorting them alphabetically? Xcode does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know thats this is not what you asking for, but you could try the [VS10x CodeMap](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/1c54d1bd-d898-4705-903f-fa4a319b50f2?SRC=Home) Visual Studio 2010 extension, it works the way you want.

But if you are very interested on changing the functionality of drop down list, i'm afraid that you would have to develop your own [navigation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb165135.aspx) bar.

Hope helps!

Comment: Hi, thanks, I'm not 'VERY' interested, but my colleague will take a look at the extension - it looks quite useful and promising :)